# find command to delete some directories and omit others not working

Tags: linux

In a directory I want to delete certain sub-directories while excluding others. Some by owner and some by name. I have configured per man page, but no files are deleted, even those not expressly excluded . While testing If I remove all the exclude parameters then all  all the files are deleted as you would expect.
I get no error when I run it, just nothing happens. Would appreciate a review of the script. Names changed to protect the innocent.

```
find /nobackup/. -name '*' -type d ! -user 'foo' \! -user 'foo1' ! -user 'foo2' ! -user 'foo3' \! -user 'foo4' ! -name 'acmecache' -delete
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add `-depth` so that trees of files can be deleted in one pass. The `-name '*'` is irrelevant.

Your description says you want to delete certain *directories*. The `-delete` will only delete empty directories. Your code as written will happily descend into the `acmecache` directory and remove any directories there that aren't owned by the_foo*_ users. I'm going to assume that's not what you intended, so you need to use `-prune`.

Try this instead. Remove the `echo` when you're happy with the result

```
find /nobackup -depth -type d \( \( -user 'foo' -o -user 'foo1' -o -user 'foo2' -o -user 'foo3' -o -user 'foo4' -o -name 'acmecache' \) -prune \) -exec echo rm -rf {} \;
```

Comment: Testing this script, nothing was deleted. Test environment is 3 directories. One owned by me, listed In the script with an –o flag, one owned by a user not listed in the script with an –o flag, and the acmecache directory owned by root. When I run the script the directory owned by the user not listed in the script with an –o flag doesn’t show in the stdout, but the rest of the directories do and no directories or files within them are deleted.

Comment: @John did you read my advice to remove the `echo` when you were happy the command was going to do what you expected?

Comment: Yes I did, thank you. The issue is that directories owned by users not called out in the script are not being deleted.

Answer (score 0):

The script seems correct.

What it does is the following: delete all directories under `/nobackup` and below that do not belong to *foo* users, excluding also the directories called *acmecache*.

The `-name '*'` argument seems completely unnecessary.

Also consider that the `-delete` only removes **empty directories**. But will print an error if the directory is not empty.